# Upload a file to a server using FTP using php

Tags: php, upload, ftp, xampp

How do I a upload a file to xampp server using FTP and php?

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$file = "localfile.txt";

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Thats all I found. Can't create my own server and access it.

Comment: Have you create an FTP account on your server? You need to setup FTP properly and need to add a user before this solution works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = "localfile.txt";
$tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];
$name = $file["name"];
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));  <-- Goes to current folder where your files is located.
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, SITE_ROOT."/FOLDERTOUPLOADTO/$name");
```

If you want to, I can give you a script where you can use multiple input files and put them in your FTP. Just contact me in a message.
And this way, you don't need the FTP login and such.

Comment: Your welcome. Please be sure to check this as Answered if it's what you need. Else I'll try to help more :).

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to setup `FileZilla` in `Xampp`(this is for Windows)

1. Start `Xampp` and Start `FileZilla` server from the Control Panel and go to the `C:\XAMPPFOLDER\FileZillaFTP`
2. Start The server interface
3. Go to Edit->Users and add a new User
4. Use `127.0.0.1` as the server name 21 as the port and the added user and password as the login details

Comment: when i start the server interface there is only a window to enter the host and a password and a port

Comment: Ok Good Luck with the rest